# How to make the items never get inside with other in different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to put webview and admob banner in one xml but the thing is when i do  they get mixed up i opened it in another device with different screen size. this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.median1.psalmsmarket.Psalms">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Pslamsview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1400px" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="450dp"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and if you seen when i open this application with size 720*1280 
it show in normal way they dont get mixed

[image]

but when i open it with a different size that will happens
[image]

Comment: Ofcourse they are going to conflict since you have specifically told the height of the webview to be 1400px... You should change the height to match parent and add layout_above adView attribute in your webview so stop them from overlapping each other

Comment: could you tell me what kinda layout you want me to add and what changes i should do on that layout

Comment: Please read carefully, "layout_above adView attribute" Its an attribute which should be placed in your webview and the value you should assign to this attribute is the ID of the AdView or you can refer to @tyczj answer

Comment: Restructure your XML. Put the adView element on top and Webview on bottom. Also include align parent bottom element to true in your adView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.median1.psalmsmarket.Psalms">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/Pslamsview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="450dp"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Change height of your `webview` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and add this property `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"`

Comment: again if i did that the webview will be behind the admob and the admob will block like 10% of the web view

Comment: No...that will not fix the error, that will simply hide the element in the back which I wouldn't recommend

Comment: Try LinearLayout as root and use weightSum property

Comment: thank you very much the thing is i never tried   android:layout_above="@+id/adView" and it working now thank you again

Comment: Lol every answer had this attribute in it but nevertheless glad you fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Do not use fix size. If you are using Relative Layout then this is the best way to ensure the preferred output -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.median1.psalmsmarket.Psalms">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Pslamsview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is correct! I have used this technique for many activity layouts. Oddly the `RelativeLayout` will give the `View` that is added first to the `Layout` more priority. `WebView` and `MapView`  objects are typically greedy--they take up all the space if allowed. Setting the priority by arranging them as the author has here, the priority is changed.

Comment: `android:layout_above="@id/adView"` will ensure that there is space for the addView. Adding the WebView after the AddView will make the WebView depth higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your layout from Relative to `LinearLayout` ,  with linear layout you can use `weightSum` concept and `layout_weight` , with this the view will get equally spaced in all screens .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.example.median1.psalmsmarket.Psalms">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Pslamsview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"  />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="450dp"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your hard height `1400px` and make it `match_parent` then set the webview to be above the adView `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"`

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/Pslamsview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />
```

Comment: if i did that the webview will be behind the admob and the admob will block like 10% of the web view

Comment: no it wont because `android:layout_above` makes sure its above the ad

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you forgot to tell him to place the AdView element above the Webview element in the XML because the ID adView will not exist when it gets to the layout_above attribute.

Comment: @Nero positioning does not matter